# Unable to create Power Bi Datasource using API

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi

I'm trying to create Power Bi data source following Microsoft provided [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/createdatasource). But getting `Bad Request` `DMTS_InvalidConnectionDetailsError` error. Here is my post data sample.

```
{
  "dataSourceType": "SQL",
  "connectionDetails": "{\"Server\":\"MySqlServer\",\"Database\":\"MySqlDatabase\"}",
  "datasourceName": "New Datasource",
  "credentialDetails": {
    "credentialType": "Basic",
    "credentials": "{\"credentialData\":[{\"name\":\"username\", \"value\":\"MyUsername\"},{\"name\":\"password\", \"value\":\"MyPassword\"}]}",
    "encryptedConnection": "Encrypted",
    "encryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
    "privacyLevel": "None"
  }
}
```

And here is the response json.

```
{
  "error": 
  {
    "code": "DMTS_InvalidConnectionDetailsError",
    "pbi.error": {
      "code": "DMTS_InvalidConnectionDetailsError",
      "parameters": {},
      "details": [],
      "exceptionCulprit": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Anybody can help please?

Answer (score 1):

The credentials from credential details need to be encrypted using the RSA algorithm before passing it to the API. You can use the algorithm from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/encrypt-credentials. Also, the name of the server needs to have double the amount of "\" characters if it has any.